# Change ViewBag to ViewData for database row

Tags: c#, database, row, viewbag, viewdata

I need change ViewBag to ViewData, because I want dynamic data. It is for Edit Action, where I change different data.

db is DataSet all tables.

Settings_Name_Columns is one table, I want only show this data, no edit.
This table has a lot of column.

How do it?

```
ViewBag.Settings = db.Settings_Name_Columns.First();
```

is equal

```
ViewData...??????????????...
```

Comment: Hey! Your requirement is not clear please update it with clear requirements.

Comment: I need  first row from Settings_Name_Columns save to ViewData. Or who you need know?